# How changing the value of dynamically input with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, material-ui, onchange

I have a dynamically time input row and I want the values will be changed correctly.

My code is: https://codesandbox.io/s/624vq8y7y3

When I run it, the values of TimeInput doesn't changing.

But I want, when I changed the input, all the inputs will be changed as we change the values.

How can I fix it?

Comment: On this.handleHChange(i, event.target.value) I get an undefined, did you mean this.handleHChange(i, event) instead?

Comment: Yes @AntonioCalvente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onChange` and `value` props are both set wrong. The `onChange` of the TimeInput doesn't receive an event value but the time, so just pass it to your own handler. Also, in your own handler code you're storing the time value in the tranches. But then in your code you're trying to get it directly from the state object. So change that to your tranch object and it'll work.

Change

```
onChange={event => this.handleHChange(i, event.target.value)}
```

to

```
onChange={time => this.handleHChange(i, time)}
```

and change the value from

```
value={this.state.heureDebut}
```

to

```
value={el.heureDebut}
```